# Mongoose Aggregate - Lookup conditionally (either user1 or user2)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm writing a DB Aggregate function to get `ChatHeads` for a user from `Messages` table.

Following is a message object from `Messages` Table

```
{
  "_id": "5c6e54c194509100146ea6da",
  "chat_id": "5bc81391767ba50013bc251c5bc58ac0ff45070013383422",
  "user1": "5bc58ac0ff45070013383422",
  "user2": "5bc81391767ba50013bc251c",
  "messageFrom": "5bc58ac0ff45070013383422",
  "dateTime": "2019-02-21T07:35:29.653Z",
  "message": "Hello ",
}
```

Depending upon the user that is making the request, the chat head should populate the other user's id to display his name/picture in the chat head.

I'm using Aggregate to get the chat heads but conditional population of the other user is what I'm getting trouble in. Following is my current query where `req.user._id` is the ID of the requesting user.

```
chat.aggregate(

{
  $match: {
      $or: [ { user1:req.user._id }, { user2:req.user._id } ]
  }
},
{
  $group:{
      _id: '$chat_id',
      entry: { $first: "$$ROOT" },

  }
}
```

As per my understanding `$lookup` with conditioning might help where `localField` should change to `entry.user1` or `entry.user2` depending upon their value.

Following is the aggregate part

```
$lookup: {
               from: "users",
               localField: < "entry.user1" or "entry.user2" depending upon condition> ,
               foreignField: "_id",
               as: "other_user"
            }
```

My Requirement

`localField` should say `entry.user1` if `entry.user1==req.user._id`

`localField` should say `entry.user2` if `entry.user2==req.user._id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this description is a bit ambiguous but I see your point and there are just two possibilities. Assuming you want to display **other** user's profile, you can use below aggregation:

```
db.messages.aggregate([
    { $match: { $or: [ { user1:req.user._id }, { user2:req.user._id } ] } },
    { $addFields: { otherUser: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$user1", req.user._id ] }, "$user2", "user1" ] } } },
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "otherUser", foreignField: "_id", as: "otherUserDetails" } }
])
```

Essentially before you run [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) to define which user's id should be used for lookup.

Comment: Worked perfectly (y)